# Detectar cor em uma área com PyAutoGUI

Tags: python, pyautogui

Gostaria de saber se existe alguma forma de detectar uma certa cor em uma área pré-definida com o PyAutoGUI usando Python. Algo como o `pixelMatchesColor`, mas para detectar a cor em uma área não em um ponto.

Comment: Com o PyAutoGUI tirar um screenshot duma região e com OpenCV detectar a presença ou não da cor o ajudaria?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Atualmente não existe a funcionalidade de se detectar a cor de uma área com o PyAutoGUI, mas existe algumas soluções utilizando funções existentes.
Se o teu objetivo é identificar a cor predominante de uma certa área, é possível fazer uma média com os valores RGB exibidos com a função, `pyautogui.pixel(x,y)`.
Agora se o objetivo é justamente conferir se em uma certa área existe algum pixel com a cor requisitada, terás de utilizar o próprio `pixelMatchesColor()` para identificar, colocando-o dentro de um laço de repetição onde as coordenadas X e Y aumentem e diminuam para formar a área desejada (recomendo um retângulo mesmo).

Comment: Já estava fazendo um print da área e detectando se uma cor existia entre as cores detectadas, porém vou testar sua solução, provavelmente irá ter um tempo de resposta melhor, obrigado.